# Can a subset have $0$ elements?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

​Let $S = \{1, 2, \dots, n \}$. Must any subset of $S$ have at least $1$ element?

For example, suppose the subset $\{ \emptyset \} \in \mathcal{P(S)}$ . Is the cardinality of $\{ \emptyset \} = 0$ or $1$?

Comment: The empty set is a subset of all sets.

Comment: Must any subset of $S$ have at least one element? No. The cardinality of $\{\varnothing\}$ is $1$.

Comment: How about the set of all numbers $1,...,n$ that are negative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The empty set is a subset of any set, and it has zero elements. That is, we have
$$\varnothing\in\mathcal{P}(S)$$
and the cardinality of $\varnothing$ is $0$. However you are correct that the cardinality of $\{\varnothing\}$ is $1$.

(It is important to understand that the set $\varnothing$ and the set $\{\varnothing\}$ are **different**. Think of $\varnothing$ as an empty bag, and think of $\{\varnothing\}$ as a bag containing an empty bag; their contents are different.)

Comment: So let $B \subset S$ and suppose $B$ has exactly $1$ element, e.g. $\{\emptyset\}, \{1\}, \{2\}, \dots$. Now let $A \subset B$. Can such a subset $A$ exist?

Comment: Choose $A=B$, or $A= \emptyset$.

Comment: $A \subset B$ not $A \subseteq B$.

Comment: Every set, as Zev mentioned above, has at least one subset (that is, the empty set).

Comment: @mathMajor: You should know that $\subset$ is used by many people as the symbol for improper inclusion, whereas $\subsetneq$ *always* denotes proper inclusion.

Comment: @mathMajor: $\varnothing$ is a subset of $B$ because **every element** of $\varnothing$ is also an element of $B$. All *none* of them. Read [the Wikipedia article on vacuous truth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth).

Comment: $\subset$ is also used as the symbol for [proper subset](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProperSubset.html)... maybe  that wasn't clear from the question.  $\subseteq$ is  the symbol for  [subset](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Subset.html).

Comment: @ZevChonoles, just want to clarify with some examples. Suppose  $A \ne B$ and $B = \{1\}$. If $A = \emptyset$ then is $A \subset B$? And is the cardinality of $A=1$? Next example: If $B = \emptyset$ and $A \subset B$ then is $A = \emptyset$? Is the cardinality of $A = 1$?

Comment: @mathMajor: ([taking some inspiration from Monty Python](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4vuW6tQ0218&t=2m22s)) *The cardinality of the empty set is zero. The empty set has zero elements. Nothing is an element of the empty set. Zero is the number of elements the empty set has. $|\varnothing|=0$. If you decide to temporarily give $\varnothing$ the name "$A$", then $|A|=0$.*

Comment: Now, regarding your questions about $\subset$, that depends on what you take "$\subset$" to mean. As Asaf has pointed out to you, some people use $\subset$ to mean "`is a subset, but not necessarily a proper subset`". You seem to follow the convention of $\subset$ meaning "`is a proper subset`". So, using your meaning: if $B=\{1\}$, then there exists precisely one set $A$ such that $A\subset B$, and this $A$ is the empty set. If $B=\varnothing$,  then there **do not exist** any sets $A$ such that $A\subset B$, not even the set $\varnothing$.

Answer (score 3):

The empty set is a subset of every set.

However $\{\varnothing\}\in\mathcal P(S)$ if and only if $\varnothing\in S$. Not every set has the empty set **as a member**.

Also, the set $\{\varnothing\}$ has one element. That element is a set itself, which is the empty set. But it is still an element.